# Enums recursivos con tipos cambiantes en Rust

Tags: recursión, haskell, enum, rust

Estoy tratando de implementar una estructura recursiva simple en Rust donde el tipo de datos que se almacenan **puede ir cambiando en cada recursión**. El cambio se produce a partir de una función cualquiera que también forma parte de la estructura:

```
// Tipo de funcion que puede recibir Operacion::Cambiar
// que indica que puede cambiar el tipo
type FuncionCambiar<T, U> = fn(T) -> U;

// Estructura recursiva
enum Operacion<T, U, F = FuncionCambiar<T, U>>
where
    F: Fn(T) -> U,
{
    Mantener(Vec<T>), // Datos fijos, caso base
    Cambiar(F, Box<Operacion<T, U>>), // Datos que cambian, recursivo
}

// En cada recursion si hay operaciones "Operacion::Cambiar", el tipo de
// Vec a devolver cambia!
fn eval<T, U>(operacion: &Operacion<T, U, FuncionCambiar<T, U>>) -> Vec<T>
where
    std::vec::Vec<T>: std::iter::FromIterator<U>,
{
    match operacion {
        Operacion::Mantener(vector) => *vector,
        Operacion::Cambiar(una_funcion, recursion) => eval(&recursion)
            .into_iter()
            .map(una_funcion)
            .collect::<Vec<T>>(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Defino una funcion que va a cambiar mis datos
    let funcion_map = |x| (1, x + 2);

    // Defino el enum recursivo con la funcion
    let operacion = Operacion::Cambiar(
        funcion_map,
        Box::new(Operacion::Mantener(vec![1, 2, 3])),
    );

    let resultado = eval(&operacion);
    println!("Resultado -> {:?}", resultado); // Esperaria [(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
}
```

Ya terminé el libro de Rust y todavía no puedo dar con la solución a este tipo de problema. En Haskell lo resolví de una manera extremadamente sencilla y sin ningún drama:

```
data Operacion a where
    Mantener :: [a] -> (Operacion a)
    Cambiar :: (a -> b) -> (Operacion a) -> (Operacion b)

eval :: Operacion a -> [a]
eval (Mantener vector) = vector
eval (Cambiar f recursion) = map f (eval recursion)
```

Con dicho programa puedo hacer `eval (Cambiar (\x -> (1, x + 2)) (Mantener [1, 2, 3]))` y arroja efectivamente `[(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]` que es lo que esperaba.

Pero no se si habrá un equivalente en Rust o voy a tener que encarar el problema con otro enfoque.

Cualquier luz sobre el tema va a ser muy agradecida

Comment: Hace tiempo que no toco rust y no sabría decir si ha cambiado algo. A pesar de las apariencias, rust no está pensado como lenguaje funcional. Pero si algo es seguro es que carece del cálculo perezoso de haskell, por lo que necesita conocer con exactitud el tipo devuelto por una función en tiempo de compilación. No obstante, creo que algo se podría hacer con _typeclasses_. Si tengo tiempo te lo miro.

Comment: Gracias @ChemaCortes! Por suerte me respondieron en el foro oficial de Rust y, efectivamente, me ofrecieron una solución con Clases. Ahora en un rato subo una posible solución, pero si tenés un mejor enfoque siempre es bueno contar con más de una respuesta. Gracias nuevamente! Link de la pregunta en el foro: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/recursive-enums-with-changing-types-in-rust/35836

Comment: ¡Genial! Es justo lo que pensaba que podría servir. Me tengo que actualizar con las _typeclasses_ de rust. No te olvides de añadir tu "respuesta" para que quede documentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como lo menciona un usuario en [mi pregunta en el foro oficial](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/recursive-enums-with-changing-types-in-rust/35836) de Rust. Este lenguaje no tiene soporte para Tipo de Datos Algebraicos Generalizados (GADTs por sus siglas en inglés) que sería la herramienta indicada para solucionar este tipo de problemas.

Como alternativa, en vez de plantear un esquema donde los tipos pertenecen al ENUM haciéndolo poco flexible, se plantea un enfoque de clases, las cuales tienen permitido introducir nuevos tipos:

```
trait Operacion<T> {
    fn eval(&self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl<T: Clone> Operacion<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn eval(&self) -> Vec<T> {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<O, T, U> Operacion<T> for (O, fn(U) -> T)
    where O: Operacion<U>,
{
    fn eval(&self) -> Vec<T> {
        self.0.eval().into_iter().map(self.1).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Defino una funcion que va a cambiar mis datos
    let funcion_map: fn(usize) -> (usize, usize) = |x| (1, x + 2);

    // Defino una tupla con datos fijos y una funcion
    let operacion = (vec![1, 2, 3], funcion_map);

    let resultado = operacion.eval();
    println!("Resultado -> {:?}", resultado); // [(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
}
```

Comment: Yo te animaba precisamente a que pusieras el código como _"autorespuesta"_ con el fin de valorarla como tal. Las [autorespuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) se consideran una mejora de calidad del conocimiento que acumula StackOverflow.

Comment: Agregado el código! Saludos!